# Object does not exist to execute method on. (SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_Registration::addNameserversToDomain)

Tags: rest, exception, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ims

I am having trouble with the addNameserversToDomain call. Every time I try to execute it I receive the error:

```
{
    "error": "Object does not exist to execute method on. (SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_Registration::addNameserversToDomain)",
    "code": "SoftLayer_Exception"
}
```

> URL :
> https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_Registration/addNameserversToDomain.json

**CURL Request**

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_Registration/addNameserversToDomain.json' \
--header 'Authorization: {{AuthToken}}' \
--header 'registrationInitParameters: true' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "nameservers": [
        "aa.com"
    ]
}'
```

Comment: you are missing the id in the request, try with this endpoint https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_Registration/registrationInitParameters/addNameserversToDomain.json  and this body  {  "parameters":[["test","support"] ]}
references: https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_Registration/addNameserversToDomain/

Comment: Hi @DanielCabero I followed the same document https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_Registration/addNameserversToDomain/ but didn't understand in header its mentioned have to pass SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_RegistrationInitParameters that doesn't work.   authenticate we have to pass Authorization but for `SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_RegistrationInitParameters` didn't know what header object we have pass

Comment: please review this link please https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/rest/ 
is how it work.